# Generate missing value in dataset using `ampute` function from `mice` library in R

Tags: r, missing-data, r-mice

I originally posted this on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) but now realize this website is more appropriate for my question.

Following this [link](https://rianneschouten.github.io/mice_ampute/vignette/ampute.html), I am trying to generate missing values to simulate a real-world situation

First I generated explanatory variables using the following code:

```
n = 50

x1 = rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 1)         
x2 = rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 1) 
x3 = rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 1)         
x4 = rnorm(n,mean = 0,sd = 1)
```

Then I generate the responsive variable by the following code.

```
z = -1 + .5*x1 + .5*x2 + .5*x3 + .5*x4 + rnorm(1,0,0.1)
pr = 1/(1+exp(z))       # pass through an inv-logit function
y = rbinom(n,1,pr)      # bernoulli response variable

data_mat <- as.data.frame(cbind(x1,x2,x3,x4,y))
```

I am trying to use the `ampute` function from the `mice` library to generate missing data based on the binary response variable.

The missing not at random case I would like to generate is as follows: when `Y = 0`, the independent variables are four times more likely to have missing data than the independent variables when `Y = 0`.

Can this be done using `ampute` function or is there an alternative way? Thank you.

Comment: While you argue that it is less of a Stats question, I think it might be better for CV because of the statistical issues associated with MNAR/MCAR/MAR. Alterantively, how  `ampute` does its "amputation"s(via `mech`) might be a good starting point. Looking at the [docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mice/versions/3.6.0/topics/ampute), specifying the weights seems like the most probable way to customize the function for your case.

Comment: I don't think there is a direct parameter to do this in the ampute function. But it is quite easy to solve. At least for your rather simple case. Just select all data from data_mat where Y = 0 and perform ampute(). Then all data where Y != 0 and also perform ampute(). So you perform ampute() seperately. By using the prop parameter you can adjust the missingness proportion. In your case you set it in the one case 4 times higher. The missingness proportion is not the only thing you can set - also think about pattern, mechanism ... all can be set by parameters.